# performClose: on a borderless window?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nswindow

Is there a way to have the method performClose: working when i use NSBorderlessWindowMask? What method do i have to override ? (if its possible)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i have overridden some methods, and it works. All I want to know now is if i didn't take it from the bad approach :)

```
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem
{
    return ([menuItem action] == @selector(performClose:) || [menuItem action] == @selector(performZoom:) || [menuItem action] == @selector(performMiniaturize:)) ? YES : [super validateMenuItem:menuItem];
}

- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)performClose:(id)sender
{
    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(windowShouldClose:)])
    {
        if(![[self delegate] windowShouldClose:self]) return;
    }
    else if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(windowShouldClose:)])
    {
        if(![self windowShouldClose:self]) return;
    }

    [self close];
}

- (void)performMiniaturize:(id)sender
{
    [self miniaturize:self];
}

- (void)performZoom:(id)sender
{
    [self zoom:self];
}
```

Comment: I cannot express in words my appreciation for this post, THANKS A LOT. Been searching for an hour to fix this.

Comment: Note that in this situation, a borderless window should also return YES for canBecomeKeyWindow.

Comment: let me know when you would come to Germany so I can pay you a beer for that! 

Answer (score 1):

Since a borderless window doesn't have a close button, `performClose:` will not work. You should instead use the `close` method. However, this method also does not call `windowShouldClose:` on the window's delegate and cannot be hooked to an IBAction. If you want these features, you could create a wrapper method to handle closing for you.

```
@interface NSWindow (BorderlessClosing)
- (IBAction)performBorderlessClose:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation NSWindow (BorderlessClosing)
- (IBAction)performBorderlessClose:(id)sender {
    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(windowShouldClose:)]) {
        if(![[self delegate] windowShouldClose:self]) return;
    } else if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(windowShouldClose:)]) {
        if(![self windowShouldClose:self]) return;
    }
    [self close];
}
@end
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but i want to use performClose: because I want the buttons in my menu bar to be hooked up with the methods of my first responder (performClose:, performZoom:, performMiniaturize:). I want the buttons in my menu, and also the keyboard shortcuts (cmd+w ...) to work for every window in my app ... Main window (borderless), but also the settings window, which is a classic NSWindow...

Answer (score 1):

As Kyle said, override your window and and add

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
```

And in your WindowController,

```
 - (IBAction)performClose:(id)sender
```

should be called when using Close MenuItem.